# Columns I created with geopandas are not visible in ArcGIS or QGIS

Tags: python-3.x, gis, shapefile, geopandas

I have a .shp file named "yeni_kadastro.shp". I read it with `gpd.read_file` and define crs without any problems. I want to compute area of each polygon in this layer. For this reason, I open a new field called "ALAN" and then compute areas with `yeni_kadastro["ALAN"] = yeni_kadastro['geometry'].area`. When I check results with `print(yeni_kadastro)`, it seems OK. Moreover, when I list names of columns or fields with `print(yeni_kadastro.columns.values)` I get `['OBJECTID' 'ADI' 'geometry' 'ALAN']` which is correct. However, when I open this .shp with ArcGIS or QGIS the field or column "ALAN" is not available. I tried to save it as a different .shp file and checked fields or columns but the field or column "ALAN" is not available.

Could you please help me about this issue?

I am looking forward to hearing from you

Thanks in advance

Mustafa

Comment: Can you show the full code including saving?

Comment: Dear martinfleis thanks for kind reply. When I was checking my code to send it to you, I realized that it is my mistake. It is working without any problems currently. But here is another question, when I add new column with geopandas, do I have to save it everytime to be able to see the column or feild in ArcGIS?

Comment: Yes. GeoPandas GeoDataFrame lives in the memory.

Comment: Thanks martinfleis